# How to isolate div in jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pause a parallax div and replace it with a static image. The jQuery code below works very well, but it kills ALL of the other divs (I only have one additional in the code below as an example). How can I just isolate the divs in the `<section>` area?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Close to Working</title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <style>
        .parallax-layer {
            position:absolute;
        }
        .hundred {
            width:auto;
            height: 390px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)">
        <img src="./images/top_logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <section>
        <button class='pushme'>Pause Sliding Images</button>
        <script>
            $(".pushme").click(function () {
                var $el = $(this);
                $el.text($el.text() == "Resume Sliding Images" ? "Pause Sliding Images": "Resume Sliding Images");
            });
        </script>
        <div class="hundred">
            <div id="port" style="position:relative;top:-15px;">
                <div style="left: 0%; margin-left: 0;" class="parallax-layer">
                    <div>
                    <img src="./images/para.png" alt="" class="fadeIn fadeIn-4s fadeIn-Delay-4s" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div style="display: none"><img src="./images/ch_logo.png" alt=""/></div>
    <script>
        $( "button" ).click(function() {
            $( "div" ).toggle( "slow" );
        });
    </script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="para3_files/jquery_002.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="para3_files/jquery_003.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="para3_files/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(xvalue){
            // Declare parallax on layers
            jQuery('.parallax-layer').parallax({
                mouseport: jQuery("#port"),
                yparallax: false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/home2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `$( "div" ).toggle( "slow" );` toggling all of your `div`s, that is because that is what it is doing.

If you use `$( "section div" ).toggle( "slow" );`, it will only toggle `div`s inside of `section`s

Comment: Beautiful!  I needed to move the closing </section> down and that was it.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm an old *nix, BBX and PERL person and the concept of targeting a nest and then the elements within that nest is nothing new, however, javascript syntax is new to me.  You saved me many hours of grief and, yes, it works perfectly.